# I continue to get "Error: Invalid DOM property `class`." despite using className

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am not sure how to debug this entirely so not really sure where it is saying the error exists... Here is the repository: https://github.com/kstaver/React-Portfolio

Error #2. Three more promise rejection errors exists as well, but I will put those in a different question.

```
Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?
h4
div
a
LinkWithRef@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:40465:7
NavLinkWithRef@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:40512:7
nav
./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Navbar.js/Navbar<@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:12120:70
div
Navigation
header
div
Header@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:581:1
Router@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:40883:7
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/React-Portfolio/static/js/bundle.js:40360:7
div
App
```

Comment: In JSX, you need to write `className="…"` instead of `class="…"` like in HTML

Answer (score 3):

Just search for `class="` in your project. There are many instances of those where you didn't use `className`.

They are in:

- src/components/About/index.js
- src/components/Resume/index.js
- src/components/Contact/index.js
- src/components/Navigation/index.js

Comment: Ah....for some reason I thought that not all of them had to be className. Silly me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace class= with className= you can use VS Code to make this update quick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).